# Scala: Side effects with collection transformations

Tags: scala, collections, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to understand views in scala via this link http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/views.html.

I didn't understand what collection transformations have/not side effects means ! ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By having side effects there is meant a situation when you execute a code in the collection transformations that closures over some external state, or have any side effect that effects anything else than the result of the transformation. Example:

```
val l = List(1, 2, 3, 4).view.map(x => {println(x); x + 1})
```

When you execute this code it will print nothing, because `view` delays the execution of `map`. Furthermore each time you try to iterate over this list, `map` will be executed, resulting in printing value more times than it was desirable.

```
  var counter = 0
  val ll = for (i <- List(1, 2, 3, 4).view)
            yield { counter += 1; i + 1}
  println(counter)      // 0
  println(ll.toList)    // this executes .force internally
  println(counter)      // 4
```

Behaves in the same way, but it is even more unexpected. `counter` increases only after the fact of iteration, and given that `ll` is lazy and delayed, the iteration may happen far more deeper in the code, resulting in `counter` being equal to 0 before that

Comment: thank you , after reading your comment and this link [https://pavelfatin.com/scala-collections-tips-and-tricks/#side-effects] I end up by the conclusion that side effects is present when the order of evaluation matters

Answer (score 0):

Scala has immutable collections (everything in scala.collection.immutable). These collection types have no operations to modfiy them, but only to get modified copies.

So for example this

```
Set(1) + 2
```

will give you a new Set containing 1 and 2, not modify the first set. The same holds for transformations as map, flatMap, filter etc.

Views do not change anything about that. The only difference between a view and the collection it is based on is, that (most) operations on views are lazy, i.e. intermediate results are not computed.

```
val l1 = List(1,2) 
val l2 = List(1,2).map(x => x + 1) // a new List(2,3) is computed here
l2.foreach(println) // the elements of l2 are just printed
```

With views:

```
val v2 = l1.view.map(x => x + 1) // nothing is computed here
v2.foreach(println) // the values are computed step by step
```

Comment: thanks,  but my question is about side effects not views